# how to convert svg string to hex ( onchain nft traits )

Tags: solidity, nft

I've tried doing

string to base64 to hex still not working any thoughts how to get this conversion?

"06054893c507054893c508054893c509054892c406064893c507064893c508064893c509064893c50a064892c406074893c507074893c508074893c509074893c50a074892c406084893c507084893c508084893c504094893c506094893c507094893c508094893c509094892c4050a4893c5060a4893c5070a4893c5080a4893c5060b4892c4080b4892c4"

i've ttied to decode this one to show the string it's seems i've been using a wrong method

Comment: Is the encoding format specified somewhere in the NFT contract ?

Comment: Converting from string to hex should be quite easy. Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: 6,5,215,210,170,7,5,215,210,170,8,5,215,210,170,9,5,215,210,170,6,6,218,209,145,7,6,218,209,145,8,6,218,209,145,9,6,218,209,145,10,6,218,209,145,6,7,218,207,126,7,7,218,207,126,8,7,218,207,126,9,7,218,207,126,10,7,217,207,126,6,8,222,209,111,7,8,222,209,111,8,8,221,209,112,4,9,223,209,90,6,9,224,208,90,7,9,224,208,90,8,9,224,209,90,9,9,223,209,90,5,10,222,204,71,6,10,222,204,71,7,10,222,204,71,8,10,221,204,72,6,11,225,205,44,8,11,225,205,44

This is the string

Comment: I asked about the solidity code. why do you want to convert an svg file to hex?